# How to find the default vpc id at runtime using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, vpc

I was wondering if there is a way to find out the default VPC ID using CF at runtime. There is no pseudo parameter I could use within the template to find out as far as I can tell. Using the cli command can achieve the result

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter "Name=isDefault, Values=true"
```

However, this would mean that I will have to create a custom CloudFormation resource and use a Lambda function just to find the default VPC id at run time. The idea is that I want to create a role in each AWS account that prevents users from launching EC2 instances into the default VPC.

Comment: As far as I know, a custom resource is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a combination of ***AWS Config*** and ***AWS Lambda*** to automatically terminate instances created in the default VPC.

I've seen it done in a demo at Re:Invent. Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGUQFEZWkho

Comment: I have considered that but this would be a reactive action. I need to create a standard user type custom role and not allow the user to perform any EC2 actions in the default VPC and any public subnets. I am thinking of leveraging resource tags to use as a condition in the policy. I was thinking something similar to the below policy condition but use subnet tags in the Condition statement if possible instead of an EC2 tag. 
                "Condition" : {
                     "StringEquals" : {
                          "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName" : "${aws:username}"
                     }

Comment: Thinking outside the box here: why not just delete the default VPC from your accounts ?

Comment: Some accounts already use it for prod workloads which is lame but it will take time to move application running there to the new custom subnets. Also, I need to restrict certain user groups from being able to create EC2 instances in public subnets across other VPCs. Currently, all subnets get a name tag that would indicate if the subnet is public or private as follows: subnet-CIDR-REGION-Type (ex. 10.0.4.0-ap-southeast-2-Public)